# External SFTP Location

Tags: marketing-cloud, ftp

I'm trying to move file from marketing cloud enhanced SFTP to an external FTP. 
The process is as follow : 
1- Extract data from a data extension
2- Zip the file extracted using "zip" data extract
3- Transfer the zipped file from marketing cloud ftp to an external SFTP.

I'm able to do the steps 1 and 2 but i get an error with the third one. In the third step i have used a file transfer to tranfer file from marketing cloud ftp to safehouse and another file transfer from safehouse to the external FTP but i get an error "File not found".

Is any one trying to do the same thing as me ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking with SMFC Support, it is not possible to do this. We can not transfer a file from marketing cloud ftp to external ftp. We can transfer from safehouse to external ftp directly.